# Solving of a linear system with parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, sympy

I have a linear system of four equations with four variables $a,b,c,d$ and two parameters $i,h$ where equations are roughly of the form 
$$a h^3 i^3 + b h^2 i^2 +c h i +d=0$$

I want to get $a,b,c,d$ in terms of $i,h$.

Is this possible in SymPy? If not, can someone recomend how to do it on some other way?

Comment: It seems that you are dealing with a system of linear equations, which is certainly possible to solve with Sympy (see [`solve`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.solve))

Comment: I've tried and as an answer I get one variable in terms of all others (something that one gets from only one equation). For some simplier systems I've got what I needed but here, although I calculated on hands that it is possible to get variables in terms of parameters, I don't get this.

Comment: Please post the actual equations

Comment: I managed to do it by reducing the system onto one parameter. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, the answer is yes, `solve` in Sympy solves systems of equations with parameters. An example using the equation you stated:

```
from sympy import *
var('a b c d i h')
eqns = [a*h**3*i**3 + b*h**2*i**2 + c*h*i + d, a+b+c+d, a-b*h*i**2 -c - d, a+b+c-h**2 - i**2]
solve(eqns, [a,b,c,d])
```

The first argument of `solve` is a list of equations, the second the list of variables to solve for. The output is a solution, presented as a dictionary:

```
{c: (h**2 + i**2)*(-h**4*i**5 + h**3*i**3 - 2*h**2*i**2 + h*i**2 + 1)/(h*i*(-h**3*i**4 + h**2*i**2 + h*i**2 - 2*h*i + 1)), 
 b: -(2*h**2 + 2*i**2)/(h*i*(h**2*i**3 + h*i**2 - h*i + 1)), 
 a: (-h**3*i**2 + h**2 - h*i**4 + i**2)/(h*i*(h**2*i**3 + h*i**2 - h*i + 1)),
 d: -h**2 - i**2}
```